# Validate method arguments through annotation in Java

Tags: java, annotations

Can we create user defined annotations to modify field values in Java?

I have a requirement that when we set values of a field accepting String type should be validated for junk characters

For example

```
@Data
class Model {

    @MyAnnotation
    String field1;
    
    @MyAnnotation
    String field2;
}
```

Here I want to create this @MyAnnotation to be called while setting the field1 and field2 value and remove the junk characters.

Is it possible?

Comment: Annotations by themself don't do anything.

Comment: What specifically are your 'junk' characters?

Comment: @JustInCoding I have the field value as 1071271 ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½  where after  1071271 there is junk characters

Comment: Create a new annotation using @interface and pass a List of Strings to it. Get this List using a method and get the values from it. Then add this method to the main method and remove the characters from the string to which you've applied the annotation. The list will contain the characters to be removed.